# Why RNN LSTM model with 92% accuracy fails on unseen data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, lstm

I have built a RNN LSTM model as three class classifier. It is giving around 94% train and test accuracy. But on testing it on real data it is giving pretty inaccurate results.Its application is related to NLP.

**My raw dataset format is like**

```
DATA        |  Class
1. String1  |    0
2. String2  |    1
3. String3  |    2
```

Accuracy, F1 Score and Confusion Matrix:-

```
Accuracy =  91.07142857142857
F1 Score =  0.9104914905591774
[[39  3  0]
 [ 2 36  4]
 [ 0  1 27]]
```

[Graph of training and validation acc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziar9.png)

So what I want to achieve is that on feeding some string, if that string contain some common words of class 0 then it should predict that string is from class 0. Any help?

Comment: What you trained your RNN on? Is it all your data? What are you using for testing?

Comment: How are your strings represented? Are they the full string, bag of words, vector representations?

Comment: @aberger  I have trained RNN on my own data which are strings(raw data) and I convert them to vector representations using 'keras Tokenizer'.

Comment: @TiagoDuque I am testing it on my own separate data which never fed into model.

Comment: I see your test set is only 112 samples, how larger is your train set? Maybe you got overfit.

Comment: @TiagoDuque Actually my dataset contains uneven data like 371 items(class 0 & 1) and 1364 items(class2) so I have taken only 371 items from every class for training and testing and after splitting I get 112 samples for testing. Well, have a look at graphs I have included.

Comment: Check whether there's too big difference between your training and testing set thesaurus and the "real data" thesaurus. Remember that when we're talking about NLP, we have a lot of different possibilities for the features, distinct to numerical problems.

Comment: Try using a different machine learning model (e.g. fastText) which handles out-of-vocabulary words better